# Text to speech API in Botium Speech Processing, gives me an ECONNREFUSEDError as response when testing in Swagger UI

Tags: botium-box

I have configured the Botium speech processing in my system. However when i test the Text to speech api, it is returning connection refused error.

Error: Calling url http://tts:59125/voices failed: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:59125

Response body:
{
"status": "error",
"message": "Calling url http://tts:59125/voices failed: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:59125"
}

Response HEader:

connection: keep-alive
content-length: 119
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Fri,02 Apr 2021 07:46:33 GMT
etag: W/"77-GrTRBV7y7SPacgMXl9QIDhTdt1k"
server: nginx/1.19.9
x-powered-by: Express

Could someone please help me with this configuration?

Comment: pls attach output of docker logs

Comment: I am not able to post the entire log here

Comment: actions.js:479 Error: Calling url http://tts:59125/voices failed: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.4:59125
    at http.js:177
    at l (runtime.js:63)
    at Generator._invoke (runtime.js:293)
    at Generator.next (runtime.js:118)
    at o (asyncToGenerator.js:5)
    at s (asyncToGenerator.js:27)
(anonymous) @ actions.js:479
Promise.catch (async)
(anonymous) @ actions.js:477
(anonymous) @ utils.js:195
(anonymous) @ bindActionCreators.js:3
(anonymous) @ wrap-actions.js:33
r @ system.js:174
(anonymous) @ system.js:461
(anonymous) @ actions.js:497
(anonymous) @ utils.js:195

Comment: whats the log output of the tts container ?